# How to check if WebSocket.server connection is open or closed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Im using node js and I cant figure out how to check if my WebSocket.Server connection is Open or Closed, is there any function like socket.readyState?

Im asking because I have a problem, when me + someone else reloads the 192....../xxx in the same moment I get an error `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3001` and I cant figure out where it blows up..

Also Id like to mention that I DO close the connection but only in one spot, here is my code example;

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
      console.log('Client: Im on... /zzz');
    })
  });

  wss.on('error', function error(err) {
    console.log(wss.clients);
    next(err);
  });

  //??
  //wss.clients.clear();

  db.all('SELECT rowid, * FROM ZZZZZZZZ', (err, rows) => {
    //idk if its ok
    if (err) next(err);

    if (rows.length == 0) {
      res.render('xxxxx/index', {
        AAA: 'empty'
      });
    } else {
      wss.close(function(err) {
        if (err) next(err);
        console.log('closing websocket at /zzz');
        server.close();
        setTimeout(function() {
          wss = new WebSocket.Server({
            port: 3001
          });
        }, 100);
      });
      res.render('xxx/index', {
        AAA: rows
      });
    }
  });
});
```

And heres what I have above my router.get

```
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();
let sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./xx/xx/xx/xxx/xx/xxx.db');
let WebSocket = require('ws');
let wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 3001 });
let server = wss._server;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you have the websocket server depend on a specific endpoint. The error you're getting is trying to tie multiple websocket servers to the same port. You only really need one websocket server to handle multiple client connections. I suggest that you would make them separate and have the websocket server run alongside of the express app.

Having endpoints to perform certain actions like closing the websocket is cool, but I would suggest authenticating them if you're doing something like that.

The error you are having is 100% server side, port 3001 is in use. It's trying to start up a websocket server on port 3001 and there is already one running. You can either use different ports, or just use the original websocket server to serve multiple clients.

To actually answer the question you asked, I believe the proper way for doing so would be to implement a heartbeat for your websocket server. That should send after `n` amount of minutes/seconds/milliseconds (I'd probably go with minutes). It's a good idea to have it bidirectional so your server and clients know when a connection has been dropped.